# Cross Product in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, linear-algebra

Consider the `Matrix`

```
A = [1., 2., 3.; 4., 5., 6]
```

and the `Vector`

```
v = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4]
```

What is the most efficient "Julianic" way to obtain a new `Matrix` whose rows are `[cross(A[1, :], v); cross([2, :], v)]` ? The result for the numbers above should be `[0.2, -0.1, 0.; 0.8, -0.1, 0.3]`

How to generalize for N rows in A?

Comment: `vcat([permutedims(cross(r,v)) for r in eachrow(A)]...)` seems okay

Comment: After a bit of debugging, @DanGetz 's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: The cross product is an operation between 3d vectors. `A[1]` is just a scalar number. And `[2]` is just a length 1 vector. Can you clarify?

Comment: @DNF I meant A[1, :], A[2, :]. I edited the question. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: If you can re-orient your matrix this operation will be much more natural and faster, and you don't have to do `permutedims`. The natural orientation of vectors in Julia is column-wise, unlike numpy.

Comment: @DNF can you give an example?

Comment: If you change the orientation of `A`, then: `A = [1.0 4.0; 2.0 5.0; 3.0 6.0]`, and `hcat([cross(a, v) for a in eachcol(A)]...)`. It is both faster and more natural. Julia Arrays are laid out in memory so that data that are consecutive along columns are consecutive in memory. It is therefore more efficient to both slice and concatenate column vectors instead of row vectors.

Comment: Thanks, @DNF. In my application, I'm actually expecting for `A` to have many more rows than columns, e.g. `A = [1, 2, 3; 1, 2, 3;....; 1, 2, 3]` where `...` means many (~1000 or more) 3d arrays. My question was posed mostly in order to use the asked operation only once. The bulk of the application will contain many operations using the columns (according to my current convention for the layout), which is why I decided to layout `A` like I did. I'd appreciate any feedback in case there are better ways to manage storage here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious built-in function for this is `mapslices`, not mentioned so far. But unfortunately it is slow, until Julia 1.9 comes out.

Julia 1.9 will also let you replace most uses of the fast (but hard-to-discover) `reduce(hcat, ...)` with `stack`. You can use this today via the Compat.jl package, which contains features from the future.

```
julia> A = [1. 2. 3.; 4. 5. 6]  # note that the original had extra commas
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  2.0  3.0
 4.0  5.0  6.0

julia> v = [.1, .2, .4];

julia> B = @btime mapslices(x -> cross(x, $v), $A; dims=2)
  min 2.866 μs, mean 3.137 μs (44 allocations, 2.08 KiB)      # Julia 1.8
  min 244.659 ns, mean 305.486 ns (4 allocations, 352 bytes)  # Julia 1.9
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.2  -0.1  0.0
 0.8  -1.0  0.3

julia> using Compat  # loads some forthcoming features

julia> B == @btime stack(cross(x, $v) for x in eachrow($A); dims=1)
  min 129.778 ns, mean 141.398 ns (3 allocations, 272 bytes)
true

julia> B == @btime transpose(reduce(hcat, [cross(a, $v) for a in eachrow($A)]))
  min 169.444 ns, mean 190.345 ns (4 allocations, 336 bytes)
true  # note this returns a lazy Transpose, not a Matrix
```

As others have said, using columns not rows is probably more natural, if you can:

```
julia> A2 = [1. 4.; 2. 5.; 3. 6.];

julia> B2 = mapslices(x -> cross(x, v), A2; dims=1)

julia> B2 == @btime stack(cross(x, $v) for x in eachcol($A2));
  min 116.812 ns, mean 129.633 ns (3 allocations, 272 bytes)

julia> B2 == @btime reduce(hcat, [cross(a, $v) for a in eachcol($A2)])
  min 168.212 ns, mean 189.909 ns (4 allocations, 336 bytes)
true
```

For handling many short vectors, you may also want to investigate using StaticArrays.jl:

```
julia> using StaticArrays

julia> v3 = SA[.1, .2, .4];

julia> A3 = reinterpret(reshape, typeof(v3), A2)  # view each col as a vector
2-element reinterpret(reshape, SVector{3, Float64}, ::Matrix{Float64}) with eltype SVector{3, Float64}:
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
 [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

julia> B2 == @btime stack(cross(x, $v3) for x in $A3);
  min 61.735 ns, mean 65.846 ns (1 allocation, 112 bytes)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [cross-product operator matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication)

```
cross_op(v) = [0.0 -v[3] v[2]; v[3] 0.0 -v[1]; -v[2] v[1] 0.0];
```

and then use it as

```
w = A*cross_op(v)
```

Comment: @DanGetz - thank you for the edits. I am a noob in Julia and the array/matrix notation still confuses me. I am still in MATLAB mode I guess.

Comment: Thank you for answer. In fact, although much talk about efficiency in other answers, in case of a matrix with many rows, this might be faster solution than other tricks because of matrix multiply optimazation.

Comment: @DanGetz - linear algebra for the win.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with dot broadcasting like this:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];

v = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4];

cross.(eachrow(A), Ref(v))
2-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [0.19999999999999996, -0.09999999999999998, 0.0]
 [0.7999999999999998, -1.0, 0.30000000000000004]
```

Note that the original `A` in the question is not valid syntax. In Julia, a literal matrix is written with rows having spaces between elements.

Comment: Nicely done. What is the reason for `Ref(v)`, just to prevent broadcasting?

Comment: This gives a `Vector{Vector{Float64}}`, whereas I'd like the result to be the same type as `A`, say, `Matrix{Float64}`. I know there are ways to transform to the type I want. Is there any way to avoid this intermediate step though?

Answer (score 2):

When expecting the *result to be the same type as `A`* create it using `similar` and fill it in a loop with the result of `cross`.

```
A = [1. 2. 3.; 4. 5. 6]
v = [.1, .2, .4]

using LinearAlgebra  #for command cross

B = similar(A)
for (i, x) in enumerate(eachrow(A))
    B[i, :] = cross(x, v)
end
B
#2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
# 0.2  -0.1  0.0
# 0.8  -1.0  0.3

using BenchmarkTools
@btime begin
    B = similar($A)
    for (i, x) in enumerate(eachrow($A))
        B[i, :] = cross(x, $v)
    end
end
#  78.340 ns (3 allocations: 272 bytes)
```

As pointed out by @DNF it will be faster to go along columns instead of rows.

```
A2 = [1. 4.; 2. 5.; 3. 6.] #Changed orientation of A

@btime begin
    B = similar($A2)
    for (j, x) in enumerate(eachcol($A2))
        B[:, j] = cross(x, $v)
    end
end
#   77.214 ns (3 allocations: 272 bytes)
```

Another option will be to use `hcat` in `reduce`.

```
@btime reduce(hcat, [cross(a, $v) for a in eachrow($A)])
#  103.328 ns (4 allocations: 336 bytes)
```

Compared with the similar method from @DNF

```
@btime hcat([cross(a, $v) for a in eachrow($A)]...)
#  124.479 ns (4 allocations: 336 bytes)
```

And to those from other answers

```
@btime cross.(eachrow($A), Ref($v))  #@AboAmmar - but returns a vector
#  104.453 ns (5 allocations: 384 bytes)

@btime vcat([permutedims(cross(r,$v)) for r in eachrow($A)]...)  #@Dan Getz
#  180.323 ns (8 allocations: 528 bytes)

@btime $A * [0.0 -$v[3] $v[2]; $v[3] 0.0 -$v[1]; -$v[2] $v[1] 0.0]  #@John Alexiou
#  263.570 ns (9 allocations: 416 bytes)

@btime [cross($A[1, :], $v), cross($A[2, :], $v)]  #@JustLearning - but returns a vector
#  107.073 ns (5 allocations: 384 bytes)

@btime mapslices(x -> cross(x, $v), $A; dims=2)  #@mcabbott
#  1.887 μs (44 allocations: 2.08 KiB)

@btime [cross(a, $v) for a in eachrow($A)]  #but returns a vector
#  73.807 ns (3 allocations: 224 bytes)

@btime [cross(a, $v) for a in eachcol($A2)]  #but returns a vector
#  71.950 ns (3 allocations: 224 bytes)
```

@mcabbott pointed that in 1.9 stack will be available which is also fast, especially when A can be used by col.

```
using Compat #for stack from v1.9
@btime stack(cross(x, $v) for x in eachrow($A); dims=1)
#  93.161 ns (3 allocations: 272 bytes)

@btime stack(cross(x, $v) for x in eachcol($A2))
#  79.622 ns (3 allocations: 272 bytes)
```

@mcabbott also showed that when using StaticArrays it could be done even faster.

```
using StaticArrays
v3 = SA[.1, .2, .4];
A3 = reinterpret(reshape, typeof(v3), A2)
@btime stack(cross(x, $v3) for x in $A3)
#  43.051 ns (1 allocation: 112 bytes)
```

What could also be done with a loop.

```
@btime begin
    B = similar($A2)
    for (i, x) in enumerate($A3)
        B[:, i] = cross(x, $v3)
    end
end
#  40.591 ns (1 allocation: 112 bytes)

@btime [cross(x, $v3) for x in $A3]  #But returns a vector
#  36.914 ns (1 allocation: 112 bytes)
```

Currently it look like that *the most efficient "Julianic" way to obtain a new `Matrix`* is a for loop in case the given data should be used as it is. In case it could be stored in a different way `stack` is as efficient as the loop but more convenient. Using *StaticArrays* will improve the performance of both.
But if the matrix has many rows

```
A = randn((10000, 3))

@btime begin
    B = similar($A)
    for (i, x) in enumerate(eachrow($A))
        B[i, :] = cross(x, $v)
    end
end
#  246.372 μs (10002 allocations: 1015.67 KiB)

@btime $A * [0.0 -$v[3] $v[2]; $v[3] 0.0 -$v[1]; -$v[2] $v[1] 0.0]
#  30.958 μs (10 allocations: 234.72 KiB)

using StaticArrays
v3 = SA[.1, .2, .4];
A3 = reinterpret(reshape, typeof(v3), A')
@btime stack(cross(x, $v3) for x in $A3)
  96.000 μs (2 allocations: 234.42 KiB)
```

the *cross-product operator matrix* given in the answer of @John Alexiou is the fastest!