Apply a function to pairs of columns from two aritrarily sized arrays in Julia
Pythonista exploring Julia here.
I have a function that takes two vectors and returns a vector.
I need to apply it to pairs of vectors from different arrays.
Consider, for example, the cross product. This how it works in Python:
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [5, 6, 7, 8],
              [9,10,11,12]])
b = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4],
              [5,6]])

a = a.reshape(3, 1, 4)      # Make arrays broadcast-compatible
b = b.reshape(3, 2, 1)

c = np.cross(a, b, axis=0)  # All cross products -> shape (3,2,4)

And this is what I got in Julia, producing the same result:
using LinearAlgebra

a = [1  2  3  4
     5  6  7  8
     9 10 11 12]
b = [1 2
     3 4
     5 6]

a = reshape(a, (3, 1, 4))  # Make arrays broadcast-compatible
b = reshape(b, (3, 2))

# eachcol() doesn't work for arbitrary arrays
c = stack(cross.(eachslice(a, dims=(2,3)), eachcol(b)))

When using arrays with arbitrary shapes, the same expression (np.cross(a, b, axis=0)) works in Python. In Julia I'm doing the following:
"eachcol() for arbitrarily shaped arrays"
eachcol(a::AbstractArray) = eachslice(a, dims=tuple(2:ndims(a)...))

"Column-wise cross product of broadcastable arrays"
cw_cross(a::AbstractArray, b::AbstractArray) = stack(cross.(eachcol(a), eachcol(b)))

So that I can use
c = cw_cross(a, b)

Are there any better alternatives, simpler or more efficient?

One way to be more efficient is to use StaticArrays where lengths are known in advance.  StaticArrays are statically sized arrays, where the size is part of the type that the compiler can use to optimize the code accessing the arrays.
In your example function, the cross function only accepts vectors of length 3.
A complementary way to be efficient is to notice when elements are bits already laid out in memory in correct order.  The memory layout just needs to be reinterpreted.  This can avoid allocating view objects for slices.
Julia stores multidimensional arrays in column-major order: consecutive elements in a column are adjacent in memory.  Julia default arrays are resizable (so they have a pointer to storage that can be reallocated), but static arrays have a constant size.  Elements of an array of statically sized immutable bits elements, such as a static vector of numbers, are also stored adjacent in memory.
In your example, the memory storing an array with columns of length 3 can be reinterpreted as an array of static vectors of length 3.
import LinearAlgebra: cross
import StaticArrays: SVector

a = [1  2  3  4
     5  6  7  8
     9 10 11 12]
b = [1 2
     3 4
     5 6]

a = reshape(a, (3, 1, 4))  # Make arrays broadcast-compatible
b = reshape(b, (3, 2))

function sa_cross(a::AbstractArray, b::AbstractArray)
    @assert 3 == first(size(a)) == first(size(b)) "cross requires column length 3"
    sa = reinterpret(reshape, SVector{3, eltype(a)}, a)
    sb = reinterpret(reshape, SVector{3, eltype(b)}, b)
    stack(cross.(sa, sb))
end

c = sa_cross(a, b)

(inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/73691541/9712582)
